# How to fork blockchain intentionally without RPC commands?

Tags: json-rpc, blockchain-fork, testing, regtest, selfish-mining

Are there any methods other than RPC command `invalidateblock <hash>` for creating forks?
I know that forks occur when two miners (nearly) simultanously each generate a block for a previous common block but is this the only natural way to fork the blockchain?

I want to test blockchain forks with multiple nodes and would like to have one node **intentionally create forks from time to time**. How can I achieve this? 
Do I need to make all nodes generate blocks simultanously and hope that randomly two or more blocks are created at the same time? - This would lead to a mess, right?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to test how your software handles arbitrarily large reorgs, right? Have you tried splitting your network into A and B, and disconnecting them from each other to create a fork?

Comment: @NickODell: I'm more interested in testing selfish mining in regtest. I want to fork the blockchain again after reorganisation in an automated fashion so everytime selfish mining fails OR wins a round of 'race' ,the blockchain is forked again to start a new selfish mine attack. Splitting is not a solution i guess since at least the selfish miner has to watch honest miners actions in order to react according to selfish mine algorithm so they need to stay connected.